# Arabic Font in Webview Javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, arabic

Why arabic text in webview JavaFX is not connected?

I use this code

```
         WebView myweb = new WebView();
         final WebEngine webengine = myweb.getEngine();   
         InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("Farhood.ttf");

         Font arabicFont =  Font.loadFont(is,10);
         webengine.loadContent("<h1  style=\"font-family:Farhood;\">بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ</h1><h1  style=\"font-family:Farhood;\">ِﻢﻳِﺣَّﺮﻟﺍ ِﻥَٰﻡْﺣَّﺮﻟﺍ ِﻩَّﻠﻟﺍ ِﻡْﺳِﺑ</h1>");
         children.add(myweb);
```

and this result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hIbX.png

Answer (score 1):

Use JRE8, supports Arabic text, and supports the @font-face  css

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Comment: I see this behavior in 1.8.0_25

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this also. Arabic words have little gaps with all fonts. Same html in browser looks fine (chrome, firefox). Adjusting the font size makes the gaps appear and disappear depending on size. Labels do this too...

Bonus: webview word wrap sometimes splits up arabic words in the middle!

Edit: running java 1.8.0_25 on Ubuntu 14.04